# Automatically switching proxy server settings

Tags: macos, network, catalina, proxy

I have a local proxy server running on my network that I'd like to route web traffic through while I'm at home. I can do this under System Preferences > Network > Advanced > Proxies, Web Proxy (HTTP) and Secure Web Proxy (HTTPS).

However, I only want to use this proxy server when I'm on my home network. It seems that this setting persists even as I change Wi-Fi networks, unlike on iOS.

And I only want to use it when I am not otherwise connected to my office's VPN.

Is there a good solution for managing this for me?